# Attach to a container generating an exception

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that is exiting prematurely due to an exception.  I want to connect to it to debug the issue but I can't seem to keep it running in order to connect to it.

This is my initial run command:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 --env-file=Environment/secret.env --name starter1 starterapp
```

If I try:

```
docker attach starter1
```

It gives:

> You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first

If I try:

```
docker start -ai starter1
```

It starts but gives me the exception and exits.

If I try:

```
docker exec -i -t starter1 /bin/bash
```

I get:

> Error response from daemon: Container 87ac5aade2d298c113bd31b50944b5095601eafc6fe29aebc046eacc76c5c2c9 is not running

I also tried:

```
docker run -it --rm starterapp /bin/bash -i
```

But it still dumps out after exception and doesn't open bash command prompt.

How do I get into a bash shell to debug the issue?  The exception is generated from kestrel (webserver) due to a missing value so I should be able to access the bash prompt issue free I just cant keep it running so I can't attach to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the entrypoint with the `--entrypoint` parameter. You can do something like:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -ti --env-file=Environment/secret.env --name starter1 --entrypoint /bin/bash starterapp
```